# How can I specify where I want my UI elements to go on orientation change in Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, button, interface-builder, orientation

Ok so I know this is a bit of a newbie question, but being that I am a newbie its ok! I have a view that I am trying to make orientation friendly in IB, and I am having some difficulties.

I have everything looking nice in portrait of course, but then when I go to landscape mode (by hitting that arrow in the top-right corner) everything gets all messed up.

Now, because of the way the view is laid out, I need to align 3 buttons along the bottom of an image view in portrait, and then in landscape, those three buttons need to be symmetrically aligned along the right side.

No combination of fiddling with those red arrows in the size inspector are rewarding me the results I am seeking. Is it possible to set up the buttons one way in one orientation in IB, and then on change, set them completely different?

I have looked all around for a useful IB tutorial, but haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I know you want to do this in IB, but if you're willing to try it programmatically, then you can move things around pretty easily. For your buttons, just implement the setCenter method like this:

`[myButton setCenter:CGPointMake(xCenter,yCenter)];`

Otherwise, if you want to use the IB, use the Autosizing options. The arrows will stretch or compress the width and height, and the bars (|-|) preserve distances from the top and bottom. If you have three buttons in a row, you can fix the left distance for the left button, the right distance for the right button and both/neither for the center button. Something like that may work.

The third option is to make a new view, call it landscapeView or something, by dragging a UIView from the library to the window with File's Owner, First Responder, View, etc. Then orient that to landscape, copy over all your UI objects, lay them out as you like, and when you rotate, replace the current view with landscapeView. The problem with this that I've found (one of many) is that you have to reconnect everything and have different IBOutlets for the labels and whatnot. T

Answer (score 0):

Using IB's autosizing features can only do so much. PengOne does a good job of describing them in his second paragraph. If they are not enough, you have to move the elements programmatically. See [Responding to Orientation Changes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW23). Otherwise, you can just use a completely different view, again as mentioned by PengOne.